# JQuery, Ajax, Json, PHP multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop through a multidimensional associative array retrieved via jquery/ajax from a php file.
The php array looks like this:

```
$pink =  array ( "newarray" => array 
( "varietyOne" => array
("name" => "Poublout", "year" => 2002),
"varietyTwo" => array
("name" => "Gerarde", "year" => 2003),
"varietyThree" => array
("name" => "Encore", "year" => 1956),
"varietyFour" => array
("name" => "Toujours", "year" => 1957),
"varietyFive" => array
("name" => "J'aime", "year" => 1958),
"varietySix" => array
("name" => "Alisee", "year" => 2001)
),
"varNumber" => array
("varietyOne",
"varietyTwo",
"varietyThree",
"varietyFour",
"varietyFive",
"varietySix"
)
);
print json_encode($pink);
```

The js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clicker').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'another.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (brandon) {
                for (var i = 0; i < brandon.newarray.length; i++) {
                    var catName = brandon.varNumber[i];
                    for (var wineName in brandon.newarray[i][catName]) {
                        console.log(branond.newarray[i][catName][wineName]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the json rather than the php:

```
{"newarray":
    {"varietyOne":{"name":"Poublout","year":2002},
     "varietyTwo":{"name":"Gerarde","year":2003},
     "varietyThree":{"name":"Encore","year":1956},
     "varietyFour":{"name":"Toujours","year":1957},
     "varietyFive":{"name":"J'aime","year":1958},
     "varietySix":{"name":"Alisee","year":2001}},
 "varNumber":
    ["varietyOne","varietyTwo","varietyThree","varietyFour","varietyFive","varietySix"]}
```

I've tried several different loops, changing my array values, but I can't make anything work.  I can call an individual key=value pair in the array, but I can't get it to loop through all values.
Thank you.

And the results of console.log(brandon)

```
Object { newarray={...}, varNumber=[6]}
newarray
Object { varietyOne={...}, varietyTwo={...}, varietyThree={...}, more...}
varietyFive
Object { name="J'aime", year=1958}
varietyFour
Object { name="Toujours", year=1957}
varietyOne
Object { name="Poublout", year=2002}
varietySix
Object { name="Alisee", year=2001}
varietyThree
Object { name="Encore", year=1956}
varietyTwo
Object { name="Gerarde", year=2003}
varNumber
["varietyOne", "varietyTwo", "varietyThree", 3 more...]
0   "varietyOne"
1   "varietyTwo"
2   "varietyThree"
3   "varietyFour"
4   "varietyFive"
5   "varietySix"
```

So, the loop now outputs to console, but I want the text to be displayed on my site.  Normally I use a $('#somediv').append(brandon.(whateverelse); and the information will appear.  In this case it does not.

Comment: You should add `header('Content-type: application/json');` to your PHP, although this probably has no impact on your current problem.

Comment: I get an object that lists the info in my array.

Comment: Can you add in the json rather than the php which generates the json?

Comment: At what point of the php? before my array or after?

Comment: Doesn't matter at what point you add it, `header()` is applied to the beginning of the response regardless.

Comment: Btw, if you can add the results of `console.log(brandon)` to the question, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the varNumber array.

All you need is:

```
for (var index in brandon.newarray) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(brandon.newarray[index]);
    console.log(brandon.newarray[index]['name']); // or brandon.newarray[index].name
    console.log(brandon.newarray[index]['year']); // or brandon.newarray[index].year
}
```

In this case, index will be `varietyOne`, `varietyTwo`, etc.

Comment: Ok, cool, but now how do I actually get it to output to my html, in an empty div?  Normally I use $('#emptydiv').append(brandon);  But this method does not work for me now.

Comment: I see you updated the question with what you want to output (sorta).

Anyway, there's a million ways to output results from a table... here's one example, a one-liner:

`for (var index in brandon.newarray) $('#somediv').append('<div>' + brandon.newarray[index]['name'] + ': ' + brandon.newarray[index]['year'] + '</div>');`

Comment: Yes, sorry, had a bit of connectivity issue.  It works very well.  Thank you much.  Does that mean I can't simply append the whole function/object/array?  I have to call an individual index=key within the array?

Comment: Well, you can do many things.

For example, you can write a function that takes an array and prints one row of data, then call that function from your loop:

`for (var index in brandon.newarray) displayRow(brandon.newarray[index]);`

Your question is a bit vague though I must say...

Comment: Ok, sorry for the vagueness.  Thanks for answering! I think that will be all for now.